Best way to code event system that has both one-to-one subscription and one-to-several subscription?
I'm trying to create an event system that can be used for all types of events that happen in my game but I'm running into this following problem.
My player HUD needs to be updated whenever an enemy dies for things like score and the current system I'm using works great since enemies publish their death to an event bus and notifies my player HUD to update the score.
However, enemies have their own HUD and whenever I use the same event system to have each enemy communicate with their own HUD on a one-to-one basis, what ends up happening is all existing enemies take damage from one source.
The end goal is I want some sort of event system in order to avoid tight coupling between my Enemy objects and their respective HUDs. How can I achieve this? Would just a simple interface for the HUD housing an event property be the best way?
Here is the EventBus implementation:
//This is the event bus. It will be the hub of activity for a event type.
public static class EventBus<T> where T : IEvent
{
    //Store all of the bindings relating to the type of an event and put all those in a hash set.
    static readonly HashSet<IEventBinding<T>> bindings = new HashSet<IEventBinding<T>>();

    //Register and deregister a binding from the bus.
    public static void Register(EventBinding<T> binding) => bindings.Add(binding);
    public static void Deregister(EventBinding<T> binding) => bindings.Remove(binding);

    //need a public method that will accept an event and invoke both the Actions on the binding
    public static void Raise(T @event)
    {
        foreach (var binding in bindings)
        {
            //no '?' needed because null checks not needed for delegates
            binding.OnEvent.Invoke(@event);
            binding.OnEventNoArgs.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

Here is the EventBinding implementation:
//concrete definition of event binding class
//explicit interface implimentation
public class EventBinding<T> : IEventBinding<T> where T : IEvent
{
    //empty delegates to avoid null checks
    Action<T> onEvent = _ => { };
    Action onEventNoArgs = () => { };
    public Action<T> OnEvent
    {
        get => onEvent;
        set => onEvent = value;
    }
    public Action OnEventNoArgs
    {
        get => onEventNoArgs;
        set => onEventNoArgs = value;
    }

    //constructors
    public EventBinding(Action<T> onEvent) => this.onEvent = onEvent;
    public EventBinding(Action onEventNoArgs) => this.OnEventNoArgs = onEventNoArgs;

    //add remove no arg actions
    public void Add(Action onEvent) => onEventNoArgs += onEvent;
    public void Remove(Action onEvent) => onEventNoArgs -= onEvent;

    //add remove actions
    public void Add(Action<T> onEvent) => onEvent += onEvent;
    public void Remove(Action<T> onEvent) => onEvent -= onEvent;
}

Here is an example event implementation used for registering, and raising events:
public struct EnemyHealthEvent : IEvent
{
    //enemy can lose health, gain health, do damage, give score to player
    public float CurrentHealth;
    public float MaxHealth;
}



However, enemies have their own HUD and whenever I use the same event system to have each enemy communicate with their own HUD on a one-to-one basis, what ends up happening is all existing enemies take damage from one source.

You're not showing where the event listeners are added or invoked, but it sounds like you have everything listening to the same event and the event doesn't specify the target.
One way to handle this is to add the target to the IEvent. For example:
public struct EnemyHealthEvent : IEvent
{
    public Enemy Target; // The Enemy that this event relates to.
    public float CurrentHealth;
    public float MaxHealth;
}

Then in your handler functions, you could do a check, for example:
void Enemy_takeDamage(EnemyHealthEvent evt) {
    if (evt.Target == expectedTarget) {
        // Respond appropriately here
    }
}

However, this could potentially have a high performance impact if many objects are receiving events for targets that they don't care about.
Normally I do something more like this:
[System.Serializable] public class HealthEvent : UnityEvent<Health> {}

public class Health : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private HealthEvent takeDamageEvent = new HealthEvent();

    public HealthEvent TakeDamageEvent => takeDamageEvent;

    public int HP { get; private set; }

    public void ApplyDamage(int value) {
        HP -= value;
        takeDamageEvent.Invoke(this);
    }

    // [...]
}

// Reusable component that you can put on anything that has health.
public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour {

    private Health health;

    public void SetHealth(Health health) {
        this.health= health;
        health.TakeDamageEvent.AddListener(OnHealthChange);
    }

    private void OnHealthChange(Health health) {
        // Update UI here
    }

    private void OnDestroy() {
        if (health!= null) health.TakeDamageEvent.RemoveListener(OnHealthChange);
    }

    // [...]
}

As for linking the health bar to the enemy, I would have my Enemy spawner invoke an event, e.g. SpawnedEnemyEvent and then have a separate HealthBar spawner that listens for this event and spawns a corresponding health bar.
This way you actually have a 1 : 1 relation between the Enemy and Health Bar without the Enemy having to be aware of the Health Bar. Depending on the design of your game and the systems that you use, you might need to use a central event pipeline like your event bus in addition to these direct events.

Myself, I usually make a Health component, which can optionally link to a ResourceBar that displays that health value. An enemy is just one of many different kinds of destructible objects that have a Health component. That way neither the enemy nor the bar need to know anything about each other, without the overhead of events messaging between them, and I don't have to code separate health tracking for enemies, players, obstacles, etc. since I can re-use the same components across each.

I see in the EnemyHealthBar example that you've tightly coupled the Enemy class to it. Is there no way to loosely couple EnemyHealthBar and Enemy for them to communicate to each other?
One thing that I confuse myself a lot with is when should we waste our time with dealing with coupling. Should we always strive for loose-coupling? When is tight-coupling the acceptable way to go? Is it better for the Enemy or Player to know about their own HUD or is it better for the HUD to know about the player via a one way dependency? It can get overwhelming and confusing. @DMGregory

@DMGregory I did include a comment "Consider putting HP into its own Health component rather than into the Enemy component." I'm just going to update the answer and replace "Enemy" with "Health".

@mtg I've updated my example, replacing the Enemy component with a reusable Health component. HealthBar is tightly coupled to Health, but Health is not coupled to HealthBar. That's perfectly fine in my mind, but there are ways you can tweak it to further reduce coupling if desired (e.g. using interfaces).

"it better for the Enemy or Player to know about their own HUD or is it better for the HUD to know about the player via a one way dependency? It can get overwhelming and confusing." In my mind the Enemy or Player should never know anything about the HUD, but the HUD should know about the Enemy/Player. It sounds like DMGregory prefers the opposite approach. There are tradeoffs to each approach, so it's partially a matter of preference. The thing you want to avoid the most is two-way coupling, where the Enemy has a reference to the HUD and the HUD has a reference to the Enemy.

@mtg Is the updated answer helpful?
